# VBA type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting a type mismatch in my simple code, and I dont understand why. Can someone explain why I am getting this error? I am getting the error on the ActiveSheet line.

```
Sub testHidden()
Dim i As Integer
Dim totalRows As Long

totalRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

ActiveSheet.Rows("1:totalRows").Hidden = False

End Sub
```

Comment: That whole line notwithstanding, you're also embedding the string "totalRows" into your statement when you want to concatenate the *variable* totalRows. Try something like `"1:" & totalRows` and see how far that gets you. It should at least move the needle to whatever other issue might be present (haven't coded VBA in Excel in a number of years).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or simply:

```
Sub testHidden()
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

Comment: I agree but be careful, the opposite is not true: "ActiveSheet.Rows.Hidden = True" (oops!) so better to be explicit on the intent. But +1 anyway because I too like tricks ;) Thanks Doug

Answer (score 1):

As per the comment by user414076 which was mostly correct:

```
Sub testHidden()
Dim i As Integer
Dim totalRows As long

totalRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
ActiveSheet.Rows("1:" + CStr(totalRows)).Hidden = False
End Sub
```

Comment: This answers Sean's question.  Pragmateek gives a better solution to the hiding rows aim of Sean's code but doesn't answer the original question (i.e. why does his code result in an error?).  Not sure why this was down voted.